# find largest array using NSMustableArray of Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray of NSArrays, I would like some help finding the NSArray with the most items in it.

Initially I have an NSArray of NSDictionaries, there is a NSString called spaces in the NSDictionarys which is comma separated. I am reading all of these values into an NSArray then storing that NSArray into the NSMutableArray.

Here is that code. I am not sure if this is the best way to do that.

```
for (int m = 0; m < axisCount; m++) {
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary  = [infoArray objectAtIndex:m];
    NSDictionary *tempSymbolsDictionary = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"Symbols"];
    NSDictionary *currentSymbolsDictionary = [tempSymbolsDictionary objectForKey:@"CurrentSymbols"];



 NSString *tempSpaceSymbolsString = [currentSymbolsDictionary objectForKey:@"SpaceSy"]; // looks something like 1;2;3;4;
    NSArray *newSpaceSysArray = [tempSpaceSymbolsString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    [findSpacingSymbolsForPositionsMArray addObject:newSpaceSymbolsArray];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you build all the arrays sequentially, why not simply keep track of 
the largest one?

```
NSArray *largestArray = nil;
for (int m = 0; m < axisCount; m++) {
    // ...
    NSArray *newSpaceSymbolsArray = [tempSpaceSymbolsString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    if (largestArray == nil || [newSpaceSymbolsArray count] > [largestArray count]) {
        largestArray = newSpaceSymbolsArray;
    }
}
```